# How do I resolve a LIBRARY_PATH Cilk build-error on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, autotools, autoconf, cilk

I am following the instructions on [Build GCC cilkplus | CilkPlus](https://www.cilkplus.org/build-gcc-cilkplus). I try to `make` and I get this error:

```
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking LIBRARY_PATH variable... contains current directory
configure: error:
*** LIBRARY_PATH shouldn't contain the current directory when
*** building gcc. Please change the environment variable
*** and run configure again.
Makefile:3965: recipe for target 'configure-stage1-gcc' failed
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-gcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/username/b-gcc'
Makefile:21970: recipe for target 'stage1-bubble' failed
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/username/b-gcc'
Makefile:894: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Ugh... building GCC from sources is a big topic. Are you building out-of-tree? I.e., you cannot build "in-place"; you must build out-of-tree or in a temp directory. Also see [Installing GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) on the GCC wiki for some pointers before you dive into someone's wrapper.

Comment: @jww, thanks for the response, I was building in a new directory that I made called "b-gcc" under $HOME/

Comment: I just added GCC version 5 and up and Cilk is built in there, so I solved the problem that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added GCC version 5 and up and Cilk is built in there, so I solved the problem that way.